# Looping through to find max value without using max()

Tags: matlab, loops, max

I'm trying to iterate in MATLAB (not allowed to use in built functions) to find the maximum value of each row in a certain matrix. I've been able to find the max value of the whole matrix but am unsure about isolating the row and finding the max value (once again without using `max()`).

My loop currently looks like this:

```
for i = 1:size(A, 1)
    for j = 1:size(A, 2)
        if A(i, j) > matrix_max
            matrix_max = A(i, j);
            row = i;
            column = j;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modified it likes the following to get each max for each row:

```
% initialize
matrix_max = zeros(size(A,1),1);  
columns = zeros(size(A,1),1); 

% find max
for i = 1:size(A, 1)
    matrix_max(i) = A(i,1);
    columns(i) =  1;
    for j = 2:size(A, 2)
        if A(i, j) > matrix_max(i)
            matrix_max(i) = A(i, j);
            columns(i) = j;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: hey! thanks very much for answering. would there be a way in making this so it outputs it on a single array or would i have to use the reshape() function in order to change it?

Answer (score 3):

You need a vector of results, not a single value. Note you *could* initialise this to zero. **Don't initialise to zero unless you know you only have positive values**. Instead, initialise to `-inf` using `-inf*ones(...)`, as all values are greater than negative infinity. Or (see the bottom code block) initialise to the first column of `A`.

```
% Set up results vector, same number of rows as A, start at negative infinity
rows_max = -inf*ones(size(A,1),1);
% Set up similar to track column number. No need to track row number as doing each row!
col_nums = zeros(size(A,1),1);
% Loop through. i and j = sqrt(-1) by default in MATLAB, use ii and jj instead
for ii = 1:size(A,1) 
    for jj = 1:size(A,2)
        if A(ii,jj) > rows_max(ii)
            rows_max(ii) = A(ii,jj);
            col_nums(ii) = jj;
        end
    end
end
```

Note that if vectorisation doesn't violate your "no built-ins" rule (it should be fine, it's making the most of the MATLAB language), then you can remove the outer (row) loop

```
rows_max = -inf*ones(size(A,1),1);
col_nums = zeros(size(A,1),1);
for jj = 1:size(A,2)
   % Get rows where current column is larger than current max stored in row_max
   idx = A(:,jj) > rows_max;
   % Store new max values
   rows_max(idx) = A(idx,jj);
   % Store new column indices
   col_nums(idx) = jj;
end
```

Even better, you can cut your loop short by 1, and initialise to the first column of `A`.

```
rows_max = A(:,1);            % Set current max to the first column
col_nums = ones(size(A,1),1); % ditto
% Loop from 2nd column now that we've already used the first column
for jj = 2:size(A,2)
   idx = A(:,jj) > rows_max;
   rows_max(idx) = A(idx,jj);
   col_nums(idx) = jj;
end
```